# Limpar o histórico do `vue-router` quando carregar menu principal

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pwa, vue-router

Em um PWA estou utilizando VueJS e estou com problemas com o botão voltar do smartphone, pois quando uso ele o PWA faz o que é mais lógico e volta para a tela anterior.

Porém eu apenas entro no PWA e faço login e quando uso o botão voltar ele volta para a tela de login, e não apenas 1 vez, mas pelo menos umas 3 vezes até de fato fechar o PWA.

Atualmente a navegação é feita utilizando `router.push('/nomeDaRota')`

A minha dúvida é: Como faço para que quando eu logar e entrar no menu principal o histórico do `vue-router` limpe e saia da aplicação sem ficar retrocedendo várias vezes na tela??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Infelizmente (ou felizmente) não é possível alterar o histórico de navegação, por motivos de segurança, os browsers não o permitem.

Caso queira buscar uma solução de contorno, pode tentar algo durante o `beforeRouteEnter`

```
beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
  next(vm => {
    // tente algo aqui usando o 'to' e o 'from'
  });
}
```